# Remove unnecessary blank page after creating an appendix

Tags: page-breaking, appendices, double-sided, blank-page

- Declaring appendices, an unnecessary blank page is created immediately after.  Leaving a 1-page break before the first appendix!?
- How can this blank page be removed.
- MWE below.

  ```
  \documentclass[twoside]{book} 
  \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

  \begin{document}
    \begin{appendices}
      \section{My first section}  
     \end{appendices}
  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `\makeatletter\@openrightfalse\makeatother` to the preamble.

Comment: `\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname` would also work, but is not really that much shorter ;-)