# How can I remove the blank page after the main title Appendix

Tags: memoir, appendices, blank-page

I am using a thesis template. My problem is similar to 
[How to remove empty page after appendix and the next chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69341/how-to-remove-empty-page-after-appendix-and-the-next-chapter?rq=1)

Yes, I have tried all those solutions but no one works for my template.

The blank page comes out after a main title 'Appendix' which occupies one entire page and followed by a blank. Then, the 'Appendix A' comes out.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\appendixpage
This is the appendix.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a Minimal Working Example and not hundreds of lines of packages for us to understand your problem. Also, you load some packages twice, like url. The babel package should be the last one loaded (except if you use hyperref). That wil save you tons of lines when you rename your commands. Plus, if you use more french than english you should load english then frenchb in the babel package.

Comment: not tried, but just before `\appendix`, insert `\cleardoublepage \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`.  this should prevent all blank pages thereafter, so if you want a blank page before (say) an index, what is needed would be more elaborate.

Comment: This doesn't work as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove unnecessary blank page after creating an appendix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14544/remove-unnecessary-blank-page-after-creating-an-appendix)

Comment: @OSryx -- don't think it's a dup -- the question cites another item that contains exactly the same suggestions as the one you've cited, and the op says "I have tried [them] all ..."

Answer (score 6):

Try using this for your style document

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside, openany]{memoir}
```

the default option is `openright` instead of `openany`, and that will remove your blank pages.

**EDIT :**

I deleted `\usepackage{frbib}` and replaced your last lines by

```
\usepackage{lipsum} % for example
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
\lipsum

% *************** Fin du style ***************
\frontmatter
%\input{front.tex} % I don't have this file
\mainmatter
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}     % Added on 17 April, 2014.
%\input{introduction/introduction.tex}
%\input{pubs/pubs.tex}                  % Publications
% bibliographie
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
{\small\bibliography{bibliographie_these}}

% *************** Appendices ***************
\appendix
\appendixpage

\section{Appendix section title}
\lipsum

\end{otherlanguage}
% *************** Back matter ***************
%
\backmatter
%\input{back.tex}

\end{document}
```

It works just fine, so your problem should come from `\input{app1/app1.tex}`.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Openany works for the entire template. But openright doesn't work. BTW, I want to keep blank pages before the appendix and remove blank page after appendix only.

Comment: So before you issue `\appendix`, issue `\cleardoublepage`; `openany` should still prevent a blank page after the Appendix page.

Comment: I have tried both \cleardoublepage and \clearpage. But no one works.

Comment: @arifle: if openany works then keep it and when you want to insert a blank page use something like "\newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}", which you can find here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page?rq=1

Comment: because for a memoir the blank page is generated so if you use openany you remove them all and just need to add new blank pages. I tried the line above and it is working.

Comment: That's ... No better solutions?

Comment: You might try the subappendix environment from the appendix package.  It functions as a section rather than a chapter.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/appendix-after-each-chapter

Answer (score 4):

Just add `oneside` and everything will be fine :)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\appendixpage
This is the appendix.
\end{document}
```

`twoside` is the default option of the [memoir](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class (documentation p5):

> Calling the class with no options is equivalent to:
>   `\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,final]{memoir}`

Answer (score 3):

Try this (minus any typos):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\nopartblankpage
\appendixpage
This is the appendix
\end{document}
```

In `memoir` the `\nopartblankpage` command inhibits a blank page after a part-like page and the command `\partpageblank` sets the normal behaviour of a blank page after a part-like page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\openany`, `\openright` and `\openleft` commands:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\openany
\appendix

\openright
\appendixpage
This is the appendix.

\end{document}
```