# Avoid page breaks after parts{..} command in memoir

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, parts

I am using the memoir class. I am curious whether I am misunderstanding something from the manual. I am trying to create a book where a `\part(...)` command does not force a new page immediately after the title. I want to add text on the same page (basically a description or abstract). I thought I could use this

```
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\relax}
```

Unfortunately, the command `\part{...}` still forces a new page. So, I instead created this

```
\newenvironment{BookPart}[1]
    {%
    \phantomsection{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}
    \stepcounter{part}
    \noindent{\sffamily\Huge\color{blue}Part~\thepart: #1}
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    }
    {%
    \clearpage
    }
```

A base example then is as follows:

```
\begin{BookPart}{Introduction}

\noindent{}This portion of the book introduces you to ...

\end{BookPart}
```

Absent that I would re-write primitives behind `\part{...}`, is this a reasonable approach? Otherwise, does this misunderstanding point to a need for clarification in the document for memoir that `\part{...}` *always* enforces a new page break regardless of how one tries to override it using `\afterpartskip{...}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a small additional declaration in the form of `\nopartblankpage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\relax}
\nopartblankpage

\begin{document}

\part{A part}

\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quote}

\vfil

\chapter{A chapter}

% <your document here>

\end{document}
```

Since the traditional `\part` ends off with `\vfil\newpage`, I manually inserted `\vfil` after whatever quote/abstract you want to place. Note that the part title-and-abstract will be vertically centred, and might shift up/down depending on the (vertical) length of the abstract.

Comment: Thank you. This command was not in the manual that I have. FWIW, the answer was addressed also here ... 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246177/how-can-i-remove-the-blank-page-after-the-main-title-appendix

Comment: The command is documented in the 2010-03-12 version of the manual. The latest version is 2015-11-11.

Comment: My apologies. I found the command in the manual. I interpreted the explanation of the default:`\newcommand*{\afterbookskip}{\vfil\newpage}` almost literally as saying that `\afterbookskip` handles the page break _entirely unto itself_. I see now, the default is actually equivalent to something like `\newcommand*{\afterbookskip}{\vfil\stateofpartblankpage{}}`, where the state of `\partblankpage` or `\nopartblankpage` is checked to decide whether to issue a `\newpage` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\openany`, `\openright` and `\openleft` commands:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\relax}

\begin{document}

\openany
\part{A part}

\openrigth
\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quote}

\vfil

\chapter{A chapter}
% <your document here>

\end{document}
```