# Appendix starts at empty page in documentclass article

Tags: appendices, appendix

Firstly, I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491904/how-do-i-remove-blank-pages-coming-between-two-chapters-in-appendix), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/start-new-chapter-on-same-page/24068#24068) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246177/how-can-i-remove-the-blank-page-after-the-main-title-appendix/246190) answer to a similar question. However, these methods all assume I'm using a different documentclass than article.

How can I make it so that my Appendix does not start at an empty page for documentclass article?

Comment: as always on this site you are much much more likely to get an answer if you provide a full, but minimal self contained document others can just copy. I just made the simplest MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test
\appendix
test
\end{document}` which generates just a single page. So please elaborate

Comment: @daleif I wish I knew how to, I currently have an 80 page document with over 30 package imports, I have no clue how to reproduce the issue I'm facing and was hoping that this was a common issue with a common fix.

Comment: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl  The best thing is that the process of making a MWE often shows you how to fix your problem.

Comment: Make a full copy of your problematic document, and then start removing. BTW why are you writing an 80 page document in article? Are you sure you are actually using the article class? It sounds more like you're using something book/report like

Comment: @daleif I'm writing my dissertation in it. To be honest, I don't even know the differences in documentclasses. You're right, though, I should probably start removing. Was hoping someone here had an easy fix.

Comment: If you are writing something that long, you probably ought to have it devided into chapters, book/report provides chapters, article does not. (Though I'd probably recommend using the KOMA classes or the memoir class instead, as they have more flexibility build in)

Comment: Without any information about the actual document, it can be anything.

Comment: @daleif I use \section, \subsection and \subsubsection to do this. Seems to work perfectly fine for my purpose. Perhaps I'm using this through package imports?

Comment: Your question does not mention anything about you using imports. As you can see, you are not giving us much to go on here. For example if you use `\include` then that will always start a new page

Comment: @daleif Well there you go. I do use \include to include new sections. This, however, has never been a problem with any of the other sections in the document. I've also tried using \imput, but to no avail.

Comment: Again you are not giving us anything to go with here. Input does not whange the page unless you have done anything. \input will behave as if the code was right here and not read from a file.

Comment: @daleif If it helps anything, as soon as I remove the booktabs package from my document the appendix jumps back to the correct position (even though all my tables are then incorrect)

Comment: Booktabs provides rules it does not affect page breaking

Comment: Given the lack of specific information, I will nevertheless make two guesses.  (1) The blank page is even-numbered, so the first page of the appendix appears on a right-hand page.  (That would be expected behavior with the `book` document class; I'm not sure about `article`, and haven't tested.)  (2) The last page with content before the appendix is very full, and is somehow causing a blank line to force another, blank, page.